# Calculate performance vs LY with shifting month dates

Tags: date, datetime, powerbi, dax

I've tried so many times to solve this, but failed.

**Question:**

- I help on a solution on how to calculate Current Year divided by last year in our Fiscal Year, month by month, where last years date differs from this years date

**Scenario**

- I want to see how we performed on revenue January 2017 vs. January 2016
- I select these date filters; YEAR = 2017 and Month = January. This will generate the dates 1st January to 31st January 2017
- But, the dates for 2016, is not 1st January to 31st January
- My company's logic is; Which DAY NAME was the 1st January of 2017 and find this first DAY NAME in January 2016 and then see which DATE this has.

**Scenario Example:**

- 2017 = 1 - 31 January and the DAY NAME for 1st January is "Sunday"
- 2016 = The date for the first Sunday in 2016 is 3rd January, therefore, the dates for January 2016 = 3 January - 2. February
- My problem is how to make a formula that takes this year and divide that on last year's date range logic

**What have I done?**

- First I created a formula; CALCULATE(SUM(Append1[SalesAmount]);SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Append1[Date]);ALL(Append1);FILTERS(Append1[Channel]))
- This worked perfectly, but this just calculates 1-31 January 2017 / 1-31 January 2016 (calendar year, not fiscal year).
- Googled through many, many Power BI post regarding Rolling months, DAX, DATE DAX and such, but i still haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Hope some of you can help me in the right direction!

Regards Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a calculated column that gives the corresponding date from the previous year as follows:

```
DateLastYear = 
    VAR CurrDate = Append1[Date]
    VAR LastYear = DATE(YEAR(CurrDate)-1,MONTH(CurrDate),DAY(CurrDate))
    VAR Offset = MOD(WEEKDAY(CurrDate) - WEEKDAY(LastYear),7)
    RETURN LastYear + Offset
```

Given this, you can create a calculated column that looks up the sales amount on those dates:

```
LastYearSalesAmount =
    LOOKUPVALUE(Append1[SalesAmount],Append1[Date],Append1[DateLastYear])
```

At this point, you should be able to create your ratio as follows:

```
DIVIDE(SUM(Append1[SalesAmount]), SUM(Append1[LastYearSalesAmount]))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for a quick and awesome reply!!

I've tried your formula, and I get this result from DateLastYear:
"An argument of function 'DATE' has the wrong data type or the result is too large or too small."

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Does it recognize that your date column is a date type or is it a string?

Comment: It stands "Date"

Comment: Does anything change if you wrap `DATEVALUE()` around `Append1[Date]`?

Comment: So, I re-imported the data tables and got past the error.  Now I receive the current error on "LastYearSalesAmount" ;

A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Dendera Are you writing it as a measure instead of a calculated column?

Comment: I'm using calculated column.   I tried this formula; LastYearSalesAmount = CALCULATE(SUM(Append1[SalesAmount]);FILTERS(Append1[DateLastYear]))    this worked, but it fetches the year I have filtered (for example 2017, not 2016).

Can't really understand it :|

Comment: Just to add: I'm creating the columns with the same table where all the values is.

Comment: @Dendera Slicers should have no effect on calculated columns as they are computed before the slicers do their thing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although it didn't solve my issue, this solution works when I use some dummy data. 

Seems like my data is too complex for this solution. Think we have to use Alteryx to solve this :)